# The Utility Bar is floated at the top. I cant see my Lightning App

Tags: lightning-apps, utility-bar, microsoft-edge

At Browser Edge, The Utility Bar is floated at the top. I cant see my Lightning App.

But At other browser like Chrome, FireFox or Safari, It works fine.(The Utility Bar is sticked to the bottom.)

**Dose anyone know why utility bar is floated at the top? Is there any solution to resolve this?**

(By the way, it only happens at Edge.)

The Edge Version is: [ Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134 @2018 Microsoft ]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSjFL.jpg)