# Lightning input showing valueMissing error with non-null value in Edge browser

Tags: lightning, lightninginput, browser, microsoft-edge

On a button press, I am attempting to validate my Lightning input fields before taking an action.

For fields marked as required, I am validating that the input field has a value with something like:

```
if (component.find("exampleInput").get("v.validity").valueMissing) {
    // Invalid input
}
```

This logic works in all browsers that I've tested except for Edge, for which with a user-inputted value of, say, `"Test"`, I see:

```
component.find("exampleInput").get("v.validity").valueMissing = true
```

and

```
component.find("exampleInput").get("v.value") = "Test"
```

Has anyone come across this issue in Edge? I'm not sure why the input component says that a value is missing.

Answer (score 1):

@friendoflore I have gone through similar issues and found few like yours:-

- [lightning:recordEditForm - MS Edge issues](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222984/lightningrecordeditform-ms-edge-issues)
- [The Utility Bar is floated at the top. I cant see my Lightning App](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222217/the-utility-bar-is-floated-at-the-top-i-cant-see-my-lightning-app)
- [Microsoft Edge ui:inputText disabled="true" not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/210161/microsoft-edge-uiinputtext-disabled-true-not-working)

Salesforce says:-

> Mozilla® Firefox®, most recent stable version Salesforce makes every
>   effort to test and support the most recent version of Firefox. For
>   configuration recommendations, see Configuring Firefox. Google
>   Chrome™, most recent stable version Chrome applies updates
>   automatically. Salesforce makes every effort to test and support the
>   most recent version. There are no configuration recommendations for
>   Chrome.
>
> Considerations for Microsoft Edge Salesforce supports the latest
>   version of Microsoft Edge for both Salesforce Classic and Lightning
>   Experience. However, the Developer Console doesn't support Microsoft
>   Edge.
>   For the best experience on machines with 8 GB of RAM in the Salesforce Console, use Chrome.